# Selenium: close tricky javascript popup inside javascript code

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, popup

I know how to close popups with Selenium, but this one is quite tricky. Here is what happens. This popup window opens after I click a button. 
When I execute this code:

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(...);
log.info("step 1");
button.click();
log.info("step 2");
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
WebElement nextButton = driver.findElement(...);
nextButton.click();
```

The step 2 part doesn't appear in the log. Eclipse freezes after the click, but the click is done and the following popup shows on the page.

Here is what I think happens. The button actually has the following javascript onclick code:

```
continueButton();return;
```

Now the popup window is launched inside the continueButton() function.

So I suppose my java code is just frozen here and waiting for Javascript to finish this function and execute the return above. But since there is this popup window blocking javascript from going on, I actually cannot close the window because I cannot close the window. If I do it manually, step 2 appears in the log and the java code execution goes on.

Is there any way to work around this, given that I have no way to change the page source?

What I have tried is to execute the javascript part separately; instead of making the click:

```
jsexecutor.execute("continueButton();")
log.info("step 1");
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
jsexecutor.execute("return;")
```

But this runs exactly in the same behaviour. The popup show but step 1 is not in the log, so the java execution is just stuck.

Comment: Can you sum up the exact manual steps you are trying to Automate? Do update the question about the next step which you would perform after accepting the alert through `alert.accept();`

Comment: I have added the next step, though I never really got to it.

Comment: @Jefeinfiltrado, the question is not that clear enough.  Is this related to this - https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2760?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of a certain facts while you invoke **`switchTo().alert()`** and next when you invoke **`findElement(...)`** to invoke **`click()`** on the `nextbutton`. When a `JS` **`Alert`** is invoked you have to wait for the `Alert` to be rendered properly in the `HTML`. Similarly once you `Accept` an `Alert` you must wait for the intended button to be `clickable` as follows :

```
log.info("step 1");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathExpression_of_button")).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
log.info("step 2");
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
new WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpathExpression_of_nextButton")))).click();
```

Comment: See the problem is not the wait. If I run your code in this case, line 3 would never get executed. That is why I have put a log there to prove it. When clicking the first button, the whole java code gets stuck in the javascript. But thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: You can always increase the timespan to optimum levels as per the JS/Ajax. That is the best practice. If `JS Alert` getting stuck and unable to come out the concerned `JavaScript` is having a bug instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here finally is my solution. Before making the click that triggers the popup window and blocks my code, I create a Thread that waits for some seconds and then gets the popup window and clicks it's close button:

```
    DelayedClicker delayedClicker = new DelayedClicker(getDriver(),
            xpath, 30, log,
            EnumXpath.POPUP_WINDOW_TITLE, null);
    delayedClicker.start();
    WebElement button = getDriver()
            .findElement(...)));
    button.click();
```

And in the Thread

```
    Thread.sleep(delay * 1000);
    if (windowTitle != null)
        switchWindowByTitle(windowTitle);
    if (frameTitle != null)
        switchFrameByTitle(frameTitle);
    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    button.click();
```

Of course it completely messi to hqve the same webdriver in two different Threads, but in this case it seems the only way. Before my code gets blocked I launch the Thread. The Thread then kills the popup, thus unblocks code and disappears.